# getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(NFC_SERVICE) Not Working in Samsung S5

Tags: android, nfc, samsung-mobile, android-beam

For some reason getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(NFC_SERVICE) is returning null in SamSung S5 even though I have NFC enabled as in the screen shot below.

[image]

And here is the code that I am using to test if NFC Service is available and it is failing the first test

```
//check for the existence of
    // NFC adapter and beaming capability

    if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(NFC_SERVICE)){
        //this device is not equipped with NFC
        makeToast("This device does not have NFC hardware.");
        return;
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        // Android Beam feature is not supported.
        makeToast("Android Beam is not supported in this device");
        return;

    }

    // Check whether NFC is enabled on device
    mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

    if (!mNfcAdapter.isEnabled()){
        makeToast("Please enable NFC");
    }

    if(!mNfcAdapter.isNdefPushEnabled()) {
        // Android Beam is disabled, show the settings UI
        // to enable Android Beam
        makeToast("Please enable Android Beam.");
        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NFCSHARING_SETTINGS));
        return;
    }
```

Is there anything I should do differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`NFC_SERVICE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#NFC_SERVICE) is not a valid value to pass to `hasSystemFeature()`. [Use `FEATURE_NFC`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_NFC).

Comment: Thank you Mark, that was it.